# how to select count of rows an other table

Tags: sql, sql-server

i'm using this query to select count of comments on other table but it give me error

```
SELECT
dbo.tblEmails.id, dbo.tblEmails.eTitle, dbo.tblEmails.ePreDesc, dbo.tblEmails.eTags, dbo.tblEmails.eFaDate, dbo.tblEmails.eViewCount,
dbo.tblEmails.ePrice, dbo.tblEmails.eImg, COUNT(tblComments.id) AS cCount
FROM
dbo.tblEmails as tblEmails
INNER JOIN
dbo.tblComments AS tblComments ON dbo.tblEmails.id = dbo.tblComments.PostID
GROUP BY 
tblEmails.id, tblEmails.eTitle, tblEmails.ePreDesc, tblEmails.eTags, tblEmails.eFaDate, tblEmails.eViewCount, tblEmails.ePrice, tblEmails.eImg
```

**UPDATE:**

error is this :

> the text,ntext, and image data types cannot be compared or
>   stored,except when using IS NULL or LIKE operator.

but i have not image data type in my table

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: "*but i have not image data type*" - are you sure `dbo.tblEmails.eImg` is not `image`? If it is image - than error text is self-descriptive, because you're using this column in `group by` statement and this presumes comparison of its values.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you haven't specified what error text is... But in this particular case it is easy to deduce.

Your problem is incorrect usage of aliases in `join` and `select`.

It should be **not**

```
INNER JOIN dbo.tblComments AS tblComments ON dbo.tblEmails.id = dbo.tblComments.PostID
```

**but**

```
INNER JOIN dbo.tblComments AS tblComments ON tblEmails.id = tblComments.PostID
```

And the same story is about select - not `dbo.tblEmails.id` but `tblEmails.id` since you've specified alias.

But note - using exact `table_name` as alias to `dbo.table_name` looks like a bad idea and may lead to confusion (and in fact, it has lead in your case).

Instead consider using short acronyms for aliases, like this:

```
SELECT
    E.id, E.eTitle, E.ePreDesc, E.eTags, 
    E.eFaDate, E.eViewCount,E.ePrice, E.eImg,
    COUNT(C.id) AS cCount
FROM dbo.tblEmails as E
    INNER JOIN dbo.tblComments AS C ON E.id = C.PostID
GROUP BY 
    E.id, E.eTitle, E.ePreDesc, E.eTags, 
    E.eFaDate, E.eViewCount,E.ePrice, E.eImg
```

Answer (score -1):

Do a sub-select to get the count:

```
SELECT dbo.tblEmails.id, dbo.tblEmails.eTitle, dbo.tblEmails.ePreDesc, dbo.tblEmails.eTags, dbo.tblEmails.eFaDate, dbo.tblEmails.eViewCount,
dbo.tblEmails.ePrice, dbo.tblEmails.eImg,
      (select COUNT(*) from dbo.tblComments
       where  dbo.tblEmails.id = dbo.tblComments.PostID) AS cCount
FROM dbo.tblEmails as tblEmails
```

Comment: Why downvote? Please explain. (Simple and easy to code and to understand.)